# react native mapbox set unique value to rotate SymbolLayer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mapbox, native

Is it possible to change the iconRotate individually for each child of a ShapeSource? Because I want to add direction arrows on a route

It's similar to this question:
https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl/issues/1173

```
<MapboxGL.ShapeSource
  id="symbolLayerSource"
  shape={{
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: featureItems
  }}>
     <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
       id='symbol'
       style={{
           iconImage: Arrow,
           iconSize: 0.3,
           iconAllowOverlap: true
           iconRotate: "unique value"
       }}>
  </MapboxGL.SymbolLayer>
</MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could divide your marker into directional arrows and then use  MapboxGL.SymbolLayer for each type

You can then filter your marker by using

```
filter={["!=", "icon", "symbol"]}
```

so your code could look something like this:

```
<MapboxGL.ShapeSource
  id="symbolLayerSource"
  shape={{
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: featureItems
  }}>
     <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
       id='symbol'
       filter={["==", "icon", "arrow_up"]}
       style={{
           iconImage: Arrow_up,
           iconSize: 0.3,
           iconAllowOverlap: true
       }}>
     <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
       id='symbol'
      filter={["==", "icon", "arrow_down"]}
       style={{
           iconImage: Arrow_down,
           iconSize: 0.3,
           iconAllowOverlap: true
       }}>
     <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
       id='symbol'
       filter={["==", "icon", "arrow_left"]}
       style={{
           iconImage: Arrow_left,
           iconSize: 0.3,
           iconAllowOverlap: true
       }}>
   <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
       id='symbol'
       filter={["==", "icon", "arrow_right"]}
       style={{
           iconImage: Arrow_right,
           iconSize: 0.3,
           iconAllowOverlap: true
       }}>
  </MapboxGL.SymbolLayer>
</MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
```